# typescript typeof string doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, string, typescript, typeof

Can anybody explain why the second variant doesn't work? Is it a bug?

```
const prints = (s: string): void => console.log(s);
var x: string | number = Date.now() % 2 ? "test" : 5;

// 1st: working
if (typeof x === "string") {
  prints(x);
}

// 2nd: not working
var typex = typeof x === "string";
if (typex) {
  prints(x);
}
```

The second variant shows the following error:

> Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
> Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBADgJwJZihGBeGAKCAuGaZMAcwEoCA3EJAE0wD4ZRIQAbAUwDo2QTcyAbgBQlAIYIYADwJEUJGAB8YYAK4BbAEYdJWACJio3MCADu2MjACkMAEwwA-DABER6M5gEArCOEB6PxgARmgCUxAEAGt5YSQAMxwoAE84DhAEqUwMLGc5UmdLAG9hGHhiNGwpIWEAX2F-QNswWgITWHComPFJZNTMrF60jKycvJJnEXjElI4qmGLSxBQKqpE6oA)

Comment: That's not a bug, but simply not supported. Code flow analysis for the latter would become way too complex way too fast.

Comment: You may want to look at [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12184) or [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24865).

Comment: @ASDFGerte your answer is the best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned at comments, the question is already exists on `github`:
[Indirect type narrowing via const](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12184) and [allow storing results of narrowing in booleans for further narrowing](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24865)

Answer (score 4):

TypeScript isn't intelligent enough to prove that `x` in the second `if` is indeed a `string`. Since `prints` only accepts a `string` and it cannot prove that `x` is a `string`, it gives an error.

The first case, where the type check happens inside the `if` conditional itself, works because TypeScript has [a special case for understanding that kind of type check](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#typeof-type-guards). However, the understanding that certain values in a certain variable could indicate the type of some other variable is more than it can handle. Yes, in this specific example, it *looks* like it should be trivial to figure it out, but it would very quickly become extremely difficult or even outright impossible for it to function in the general case.

If you absolutely want the second case to work, despite the type check being separate from the `if`, you need to provide TypeScript with extra information by explicitly casting the value. For instance, using `prints(x as string)` means "I guarantee that is is always a `string`. If it's not, it's my fault when the program explodes." This type of cast is a signal to TypeScript that the developer knows something that it doesn't understand and blindly trusts it.

Comment: I find it fascinating that the first case even works. Do you happen to have a link where we can read more on how typescript handles if-conditionals?

Comment: @FreemanLambda https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#typeof-type-guards

Comment: Thanks. The link explains very well what typescript does behind the scenes. @BambooleanLogic: maybe you can add the docu-link to your answer.

Comment: @FreemanLambda it is one of the main topic of TS: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html